# VBscript - Hot to Write to a specific blank line?

Tags: vbscript

I need to insert a strText to line 14 in a template.txt file.  Line 14 will always be blank before writing (sort of like appending I guess).

What I really need is to copy line 21 to line 14.  Not sure what is the easier method to achieve this?

Here is what I have so far but not working.  Below code is the template.txt.

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DIM Infile : Infile = "C:\template.txt"     
Set tempFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (Infile)
strText = tempFile.ReadAll
tempFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, "","Channel_LandWaterMask = 3.0")
Set tempFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (Infile, 2)
tempfile.Writeline 14, strNewText    ‘(How would I write this???)
tempFile.Close
```

Here is the template.txt:

```
; Resample INF script for
; Section_YY  XX_ZZZZ

[Source]
Type                  = MultiSource
NumberOfSources       = 2

[Source1]
Type                  = GeoTIFF
Layer                 = Imagery
SourceDir             = "S:\XX\Section_YY\Images"
SourceFile            = "XX_ZZZZ_CC.tif"
Variation             = DAY

[Source2]
Type                  = GeoTIFF
Layer                 = Imagery
SourceDir             = "S:\XX\Section_YY\Images"
SourceFile            = "XX_ZZZZ_LM.tif"
Variation             = Night
Channel_LandWaterMask = 3.0


[Source3]
Type                  = GeoTIFF
Layer                 = None
SourceDir             = "S:\XX\Section_YY\Images"
SourceFile            = "XX_ZZZZ_WM.tif"
SamplingMethod        = Gaussian


[Destination]
DestDir               = "S:\2_Output\Section_YY"
DestBaseFileName      = "XX_ZZZZ"
DestFileType          = BGL
LOD                   = Auto
UseSourceDimensions   = 1
CompressionQuality    = 85
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below example:

```
sContent = ReadTextFile("C:\template.txt", 0)
aContent = Split(sContent, vbCrLf)
aContent(13) = aContent(20) & vbCrLf & aContent(13)
sContent = Join(aContent, vbCrLf)
WriteTextFile sContent, "C:\template.txt", 0

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, lFormat)
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sContent, sPath, lFormat)
    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, lFormat)
        .Write sContent
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that it inserts the content of the line 21 before the line 14, thus preserving newline, since the content of the line 14 are newline chars. If you want just replace, then use `aContent(13) = aContent(20)` instead of `aContent(13) = aContent(20) & vbCrLf & aContent(13)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Count=Count + 1
    Line=Inp.readline
    If Count = 14 then
        outp.writeline "My line 14"
    Else
        outp.writeline Line
    End If
Loop
```

Is the pattern for your type of problem. Read a line, make a decision, write something.